# RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR works from block and not in procedure

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Today, I followed [the instructions given](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-s3-integration.html) to perform Oracle RDS integration with S3 to import files from S3 bucket into a database directory.

I was able to perform all the steps well and able to see the files imported from my S3 bucket in the `DATA_PUMP_DIR` directory on the RDS instance.

When I run the query

```
SELECT filename FROM table(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) order by mtime;
```

I get the output listing the files I imported.

Now, I am planning to get these files in a PLSQL block and the issue arises here. When I run something like this:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR fn in (SELECT * FROM table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) order by mtime)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('File name is ' || fn.filename);
  END LOOP;  
END;
```

I can see the output in the dbms output window.

However, when I try to call this **inside a procedure** like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1 IS
BEGIN
  FOR fn in (SELECT * FROM table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) order by mtime)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('File name is ' || fn.filename);
  END LOOP;  
END test1;
```

I receive the error:

> 3/14     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   3/43     PL/SQL: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

I searched online for this error and couldn't get any leads.

I tried writing the procedure with invoker rights

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1 AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS
```

and it still gave me the same error.

Can someone please throw light on this?

Comment: Can you check if it is a role privilege issue by issuing `set role none` and seeing if your direct query and anonymous block now error too?

Comment: Hi Alex, I did that too... And this is the error:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Comment: Right, which confirms the issue is privileges granted via a role; but then it's strange that `authid current_user` didn't resolve it. Interesting. Are you able to get the necessary privileges granted directly to the owner of the procedure? (It might be directory privileges rather than package privs.)

Comment: Alex, any query that can list the privileges on the directory?  
I am not sure if I understood your suggestion right..

Answer (score 0):

You will need following grants to owner of the procedure. Probably from your DBA.

Grant execute on rdsadmin.RDSADMIN_S3_TASKS to <procedure_Owner>;